# Having an issue trying to create a constructor in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, constructor

For some reason, I'm not able to successfully create a constructor for my Exponent class.  I'm using the same syntax as I did for a previous class I wrote, that didn't have this issue, but every time I try to name my constructor the same name as my class, with no return value or parameters in the FPL, I keep getting "Must use "class" tag to refer to "Exponent" in this scope."

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Exponent
{
    int Number, BaseNumber, Exponent, Total;

public:

    Exponent();//get constructor working, set total to 1 (remove  number to 0 with static int and increment each time on input

    int Power(const int &BN, const int &Ex);
    void InputAndDisplay();
    void Display();
};
```

Here's another specification file I wrote, using the same syntax on the constructor, but no errors occur like the first one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

class MyFloat
{
    enum {DefaultSizeTen=10};
    char *Number;

    int NumberOfDigits;
    int MaxNumberOfDigits;

public:

    ~MyFloat();

    MyFloat(const MyFloat & RHS);
    MyFloat();
    MyFloat(unsigned int Input);

    int Digits();
    int MaxDigits();

    MyFloat operator= (const char *Input);
    MyFloat operator= (const MyFloat &X);

    int operator== (const MyFloat &x);

    MyFloat operator+ (const MyFloat &X);
    int operator> (const MyFloat &x);

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &Out, const MyFloat & X);
    friend istream& operator>> (istream &In, MyFloat & X);

};
```

What am I doing wrong?  I know it will be something simple that I'm overlooking, but I can't find it.

Comment: You have a variable named the same as the class.  Xcode should tell you the line the error is on so you know where to look.

Comment: Yep, changing Exponent to ExponentNumber fixed it entirely.  I never even thought of that.  Interesting.  I would assume I could have a class name the same as a variable name, and also the same as the constructor name, and the compiler would be able to differentiate because ones a class, ones a function, and ones a variable.  So, would it of been possible to keep the variable name "Exponent," and go with Xcode's suggestion of using "class" before the constructor name?  That doesn't seem like it would be a working solution.

Comment: The declaration of a variable with the same name as the class shadows the class name so when you use it later the compiler doesn't know which one you are referring to, the class or the variable.  `class Exponent` resolves the ambiguity but then that's invalid syntax.